# Is there an easy way to handle BJ concurency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, resque

Is there a way to set jobs in BJ and make sure that 2 of a certain "type" are not running concurrently?

We are running 24 unicorns and it will allow a BJ to startup for each one of those. This is not a big deal b/c we like multiple job handlers knocking out background task. The exception is a data import. We want to be able to tell it not to run more than one of those at a time.

Is this possible in BJ or should we just move over to something like resque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to constrain your data import jobs to a certain priority level, and then make sure that only a single delayed job is picking up jobs of that priority. For example, if you wanted to let all your other jobs run from priority 0 to 99, and have your data import jobs run at priority 100, then you could have all your delayed job workers run from a min_priority of 0 to a max_priority of 99 and then you could have one delayed job worker running from min_priority 100 to max_priority 100, ensuring that only a single worker was running those jobs. This would ensure that no two import data jobs (priority 100) were running at the same time.

Comment: We are actually using Background Job not Delayed Job https://github.com/jkraemer/bj ... that is part of the question, should we just make the switch to delayed job or resque

Comment: Definitely. I don't think you need to fully move to Resque. You'll get a lot of benefits simply moving to DelayedJob.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you can start BJs in different priority levels, so I would definitely recommend a switch to delayed_job. It's a highly used gem that is kept up to date, so the support is good as well.

Comment: Old question. Awarding answer since the comment further explains answer and we actually did end up moving to resque.